# pdfjs error : The API version "2.16.105" does not match the Worker version "3.1.34".'

Tags: pdfjs-dist

When I try to use pdfjs in vue for review PDFfile, I get this error. Can anyone tell me how to solve this?

Here is my code:

```
const pdfjsLib = require('pdfjs-dist/legacy/build/pdf.js')


pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc =
      'https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js'
    pdfjsLib
      .getDocument("../assets/pdf/活動切結書.pdf'")
      .promise.then((doc) => {
        console.log(doc)
      })
```

https://support.neat.com/neatapp/error-the-api-version-does-not-match-the-worker-version

I find this solution, that says to clear your browser's cookies. I have done this, but it doesn't get rid of my error.

Comment: See https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/10997#issuecomment-743726146 for a viable answer.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that helped me was replacing the link:

```
<script src="~/js/libs/pdf.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="//mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.js"></script>
```

Having dealt with this error myself, I can say: your 'pdfjs-dist/legacy/build/pdf.js' points to the downloaded library in the project folder, and the second 'https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js' points to the library on the network and their versions differ.

It is required that both versions be exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a local `pdf.js` from your dependency, use the `pdf.worker.js` from the same dependency. If you want to use files hosted online by `mozilla.github.io`, both `pdf.js` and `pdf.worker.js` should use the online one.

The PDF.js use web worker, the main thread bundle is `pdf.js`, the web worker bundle is `pdf.worker.js`, they must collaborate with each other to make thing done. If the build versions of the two bundles do not match, there is a high chance that they will not align with each other.

The matched version rule check avoiding spending lot of time to trace bugs caused by such situation. If you are sure that you use exactly same version, but still get such error, try to clear browser cache, the web browser normally  will cache JavaScript file request.